# Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and back, playing with secure boot

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8.1, secure-boot

On a Samsung NP900X3C, Windows 8.1 is installed. I would like to test Windows 10 on this machine and for that, I purchased a separate disk so that if it fails, I can just revert to the previous Windows 8.1 disk.

However, when I switch to the new disk and start the computer, I get an error message related to secure boot. Seems like I should disable it. However, since I'm ignorant about those things, I fear that after installing Windows 10 and doing my tests, if I revert to the old disk, it won't boot anymore, even if reenabling Secure Boot. I see in the bios that there is a secure boot configurations section with some signatures. Will my attempt modify something in those keys?

So in brief, my question is: can I disable secure boot, boot from a windows 10 usb key (which does not seem to be an option right now when secure boot is enabled), install windows 10 on the new drive, then revert back to the old disk and having it boot normally with secure boot still off or back on?

Comment: You should be able to install Windows 10 with Secure Boot enabled.  If it's not working the problem is likely the installation media.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep. Don't worry about it. You can always switch back.

[image: Instructions for disabling secure boot and switching UEFI to BIOS on a Samsung laptop]

You'd probably have to set the settings as you've found them (secure boot on, and UEFI) to have it boot normally with the old disk.

Comment: Please don't use images of text. It's much better to include the text itself, requiring only some small formatting. Include also the link to where you got the text from.

Comment: Thank you. You are right, I did it and was able to switch back without any issue.